# Nativescript-vue Autocomplete using remote json

Tags: autocomplete, nativescript

I'm desperately trying to make this work, but haven't found much documentation about it, except for [this tutorial](https://docs.nativescript.org/vuejs/ns-ui/AutoCompleteTextView/aync-data#using-async-data-fetch-with-radautocompletetextview).

However, it seems to be written in TypeScript (which is strange), so using this code brings 2 errors:

> 'types' can only be used in a .ts file.

Here is the code:

```
import * as http from 'tns-core-modules/http';

export default {
  template: `
  <Page>
    <StackLayout>
      <Label text="Select airport"></Label>
      <RadAutoCompleteTextView ref="autocomplete"
                               displayMode="plain"
                               suggestMode="Suggest"
                               :items="dataItems">
        <SuggestionView ~suggestionView suggestionViewHeight="300">
          <StackLayout v-suggestionItemTemplate orientation="vertical" padding="10">
            <v-template>
              <Label :text="item.text"></Label>
            </v-template>
          </StackLayout>
        </SuggestionView>
      </RadAutoCompleteTextView>
    </StackLayout>
  </Page>
  `,
  data () {
    return {
      dataItems: new ObservableArray(),
    };
  },
  mounted () {
    const jsonUrl = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/telerik/nativescript-ui-samples/master/examples-data/airports.json';

    this.$refs.autocomplete.setLoadSuggestionsAsync((text) => {
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          http.getJSON(jsonUrl).then((r: any) => {
              const airportsCollection = r.airports;
              const items: Array<TokenModel> = new Array();
              for (let i = 0; i < airportsCollection.length; i++) {
                  items.push(new TokenModel(airportsCollection[i].FIELD2, null));
              }
              resolve(items);
          }).catch((err) => {
              const message = `Error fetching remote data from ${jsonUrl}: ${err.message}`;
              console.log(message);
              alert(message);
              reject();
          });
      });

      return promise;
    });
  },
};
```

Thanks for enlightening me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the typings.

```
http.getJSON(jsonUrl).then((r: any) => {
```

will become

```
http.getJSON(jsonUrl).then((r) => {
```

Also

```
const items: Array<TokenModel> = new Array();
```

will become

```
const items = new Array();
```

Comment: Did this, but now I've got a new error : **ObservableArray is not defined**

Comment: You were supposed to import it - `import { ObservableArray } from 'tns-core-modules/data/observable-array';`

Comment: Did this, and had the same error with TokenModel so I imported it as well (`import { TokenModel } from 'nativescript-ui-autocomplete'` and now its working fine ! Thanks !

Answer (score -1):

I just ran into something similar and while I can get this working I'm a bit confused as to how when I set the AutoComplete items to the local dataItems array I never see in the setLoad